# Does the apple touch icon have to be in the root folder?

Tags: html, ios, icons

A seemingly simple question that I can't find a clear answer to.

Does the apple touch icon have to be in the root folder of my site?

```
<link href="http://example/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" />
```

Or is it okay if I place it in another location?

```
<link href="http://www.yoursite.com/some/other/folder/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" />
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Not necessarily. From the [Safari Web Content Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH1-SW1), the [Configuring Web Applications section](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html) states:

> - To specify an icon for the entire website (every page on the website), place an icon file in PNG format in the root document folder
>     called `apple-touch-icon.png`
> - To specify an icon for a single webpage or replace the website icon with a webpage-specific icon, add a link element to the webpage, as
>     in:
>
>   - `<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/custom_icon.png">`
> - To specify multiple icons for different device resolutions—for example, support both iPhone and iPad devices—add a `sizes` attribute
>     to each link element as follows:
>
>   - `<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="touch-icon-iphone.png">`
>   - `<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="touch-icon-ipad.png">`
>   - `<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="touch-icon-iphone-retina.png">`
>   - `<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="touch-icon-ipad-retina.png">`
>
> The icon that is the most appropriate size for the device is used. If
>   no sizes attribute is set, the element’s size defaults to 60 x 60.

You should be able to place it in another folder and use the `link` elements to refer the browser to the alternate location of the `apple-touch-icon` file, and have it work just fine.

Comment: ...so to answer the OP, **yes**, the `apple-touch-icon.png` has to be in the **root** folder (if you want it to apply to the whole site).